# How to check if it's a HomePage/Frontpage?

Tags: bolt-cms

In BOLT CMS how do I check if the current page is a homepage?

I need to check on `_footer.twig` file that if it's homepage then make the footer sticky.

Sorry if i sound blunt but I searched on the internet and on the default templates but didn't find a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the template? From the [Bolt 3.0 cheatsheet](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.0/cheatsheet#the-app-request-variable), you can check to see if `{{ app.request.get('_route') }}` is the same route as the homepage.